# How do I convert a DataSet to a DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Here is my code -- I simply need to convert a SQL DataSet into a DataTable in asp.net 4.5. I can't seem to figure it out. There are many posts doing the opposite, but none that I can find that clearly answers.

```
public static DataTable getGender()
{
    DataTable DT = default(DataTable);        
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CnnString.ConnectionString.ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ns_gender_get", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        //Fill the Dataset
        da.Fill(ds, "Results");
        DT = ds.Tables(0);     

       //**GOAL:  I need to assign the DS.Table(0) to the DT (dataTable) so when this method is called it will return the table rows in the DT. 

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
        con = null;
    }
    return DT;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just returning the table? Instead of DT = ds.Tables[0]; use return ds.Tables[0];

Comment: Thanks... I finally found it (just after posting this!!) ds.Tables.Add(DT);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, a [`DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx) contains a collection of [`DataTables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx). You can just take the first table:

```
DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
```

On the other hand, you can use a `DataAdpter` to fill a `DataTable` if you want, for sample:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

See more in:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter

-- Edits by original author of the question (for anyone else looking)
The simple solution finally hit me --

```
 ds.Tables.Add(DT); // Code on how to add a table to a dataset!
```

[Here is a great way to speed up your code!!](http://www.cshandler.com/2011/10/fastest-way-to-populate-datatable-using.html)

Comment: I found a solution -- ds.Tables.Add(DT);  -- so easy it almost hurts. Thanks!!